# UIScrollView added in code is not being scrolled anymore

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

This is what I simply do in code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let scroll = UIScrollView()
    scroll.backgroundColor = .yellow
    scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scroll, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scroll, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scroll, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scroll, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    view.addSubview(scroll)
    view.addConstraints([leading, trailing, top, bottom])

    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "helloo, my new text"
    label.backgroundColor = .orange
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let leading2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scroll, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let trailing2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scroll, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let top2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scroll, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)
    let bottom2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scroll, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 400)
    let height2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 600)

    scroll.addSubview(label)
    label.addConstraint(height2)
    scroll.addConstraints([leading2, trailing2, top2, bottom2])
    scroll.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

This is how it looks on the screen:

[image]

But I cannot scroll it at all. Why? What is wrong here?

I know there is a lot of examples and questions on SO, but not even one works.

Comment: Something is wrong with constraints given to UILabel and UIScrollView. if you want scroll vertically than you constraint it vertically along with UILabel.

Comment: what is wrong?;) I really think about this a long time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given wrong bottom constraint to label. Change the constant value from 400 to 0.

```
let bottom2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scroll, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
```

[image]

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk: Because scrollview uses this info to calculate its content size and scrollview only scrolls if its content size is more than its original frame size.